# jQuery append to the closest element as I unhide

Tags: jquery, string, append

Hi i have jQuery function which shows the first three elements that have been ticked and hides the rest. I have a function that un hides the checkboxes one at a time by the click of the add button.

I want to take this one step closer, originally I had a static remove button however now I want to have this "remove button" append with jQuery as I only want this button to be visible if a user has clicked add and it removes the corresponding tr.

I have the code to remove just not to append it seems to add it to all the rows which is obvious as I have referred to a class. rather than somewhere specific but I am unsure of how I should implement this.

any help will be very much welcomed!

My code is below or view a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gutigrewal90/HCRmQ/1/)

```
  $("#add").click(function () {
        $(".contact_numbers:hidden:first").fadeIn("slow");
        $( ".contact_numbers" ).append( "<a href='#' class='remove'>Remove</a>");
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gutigrewal90/HCRmQ/1/)

Use [*fadeIn duration complete*](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/#fadeIn-duration-complete) callback function

> A function to call once the animation is complete

```
$("#add").click(function () {
    $(".contact_numbers:hidden:first").fadeIn("slow", function () {
        $(this).closest('.contact_numbers').append("<a href='#' class='remove'>Remove</a>")
    });
});
```

Reference

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Better code

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/HCRmQ/3/)

```
$("#add").click(function () {
    $(".contact_numbers:hidden:first").fadeIn("slow", function () {
        $(this).closest('.contact_numbers').find('.remove').remove();
        $(this).closest('.contact_numbers').append("<a href='#' class='remove'>Remove</a>")
    });
});
```

**Updated after Op's comment**

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/HCRmQ/4/)

```
$("#add").click(function () {
    $(".contact_numbers:hidden:first").fadeIn("slow", function () {
        $(this).closest('.contact_numbers').find('.remove').remove();
        $(this).closest('.contact_numbers').find('td:last').append("<a href='#' class='remove'>Remove</a>")
    });
});
```

Comment: brilliant thanks! any idea how I could get it to display in the td input_number so it doesn't appear outside of the table?

Comment: if you see the jsfiddle the remove link appears outside of the table, I want this to appear by the side of the telephone number, I've named this td class as "input_number" , you understand what I mean?